# What's the reading of 傾げる? かしげる or かたげる?

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching http://youtu.be/FiqsDshUSDA?t=6m40s. At the 6th minute, he reads 傾げたく as かしげたく.

[Jisho.org lists both readings](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%82%BE%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%20&eng=&dict=edict).

[Goo's dictionary gives a preference for the かしげる reading](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E5%82%BE%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B/m0u/) (insofar as かたげる lists かしげる as a meaning).

Another site claims that the かしげる reading is [一般 in contemporary Japanese](https://japanknowledge.com/articles/blognihongo/entry.html?entryid=213).

My question is this:

1. Is it acceptable to pronounce it かたげる?
2. How is the difference characterized between using the two pronunciations (if it is acceptable to say it かたげる)? [nuance, region, antiquated sound]

Comment: It occurs to me that かたげる might be derived from かたむける via かたんげる, much like ひがし is derived from ひむかし via ひんがし.

Comment: @ZhenLin does that occur to you for a reason like a 語源 or is just a wild guess?

Comment: @virmaior I think /g/ occurred later in the development of Japanese than /k/, and a common source of /g/ in native words is from prenasalization, so it seems like a rather plausible guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't deny the dictionary, and I feel I have heard "かたげる" somewhere in the past, but I can say "かたげる" is very rare.

Even かしげる is quite uncommon in the modern 標準語, and I can hardly expect this word used except in the idiom "首をかしげる". 傾【かし】ぐ/傾【かし】げる has been almost completely replaced by 傾【かたむ】く/傾【かたむ】ける, I think.

> 家の柱が傾**く** (かたむく: OK)
>
> 家の柱が傾**ぐ** (かしぐ: uncommon, かたぐ: ???)

Comment: I think I can infer from this what I need: basically knowing かたげる is pretty useless. Knowing かしげる is useful only for the 首を傾げる expression. Using かたげる instead of かしげる would be uncommon but not to the point where knowledgeable folks would call it an error.